# Implement regex into JFormattedTextField

Tags: java, regex

I would like to use regex patterns in jFormattedTextField (or if possible in JTextField, doesnt really matter if the job is done). I know about using MaskFormatter and DocumentFilter but I was wondering if it was possible by using regex pattern.

Here's the code I tried:

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;

public class Test1 {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        String regex = "[a-z]";
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        Matcher r = pt.matcher("(.*)([a-z])");
        JFormattedTextField ft = new JFormattedTextField(pt);

        JTextField testField = new JTextField();
        ft.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
                if (!r.find()) {
                    testField.setText("not found");
                } else
                    testField.setText("found");
            }
        });
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        frame.add(ft);
        frame.add(testField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

But it doesnt work (keeps displaying "not found"). Is there some way to do this? Because I feel more comfortable using regex since I have been practicing it for a while.

Comment: I would expect this code to return `found` all the time, since you are looking for any lowercase Latin letter (as `[a-z]` is your pattern) in `(.*)([a-z])` string. Have a look at [this demo](http://ideone.com/h5r2uz). Did you intend to use `Matcher r = pt.matcher(testField.getText());`? Please clarify your question with examples.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure why you are searching your pattern for matches are you trying to do the following?

```
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import javax.swing.JFormattedTextField;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.event.CaretEvent;
import javax.swing.event.CaretListener;

public class Test1 {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        String regex = "[a-z]";
        Pattern pt = Pattern.compile(regex);
        JFormattedTextField ft = new JFormattedTextField(pt);

        JTextField testField = new JTextField();
        ft.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
            public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {

                Matcher r = pt.matcher(ft.getText());
                if (!r.find()) {
                    testField.setText("not found");
                } else
                    testField.setText("found");
            }
        });
        frame.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 1));
        frame.add(ft);
        frame.add(testField);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a `Matcher` at all; `String` has the `matches()` method that is more convenient.

Assuming "found" means finding a letter in the input:

```
ft.addCaretListener(new CaretListener() {
    public void caretUpdate(CaretEvent e) {
        if (ft.getText().matches(".*[a-z].*"))
            testField.setText("not found");
        else
            testField.setText("found");
    }
});
```

Or if you prefer you can use a ternary to express it in one line:

```
testField.setText((ft.getText().matches(".*[a-z].*") ? "" : "not ") + "found");
```